# Multilingual Date format

Tags: c#, date-formatting

I have to create multilingual website in C# .net, I am getting issue while I change culture other than default(i.e: en-us) because date format is changed with culture and all calender's and ajax calender extender showing error. I also get error while I fire some SQL query just because my database culture is en-us and date is in other culture like Arabic, Chinese etc...

Please suggest.

Comment: Date formatting is a matter of presentation. Use it internally in your application in one format and stick with that.

Comment: @Jeroen : I try to fix date format, for this I defined date format in web.config file and use same when culture changes but its not working here is my sample code.

CultureInfo newCulture = (CultureInfo)System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
newCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultDateFormat"];
newCulture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Separator"];
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;

Comment: My Date format is MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt
When I select Calender1.SelectedDate in Arabic culture its return "03/08/34 12:00:00 ص" as date, but my database only accept en-us culture and SQL query returns error as datetime out of bound.
I can't change my date format because I am working on a live site

Comment: By the time this is getting anywhere *close* to an SQL database, you ought to have already parsed it into a `DateTime` and be passing that (via parameters) to the database, without it ever becoming a string again.

Answer (score 1):

For instance, a [Calendar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.UI.WebControls.Calendar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
You wanna want which date was selected, then use `SelectedDate` which returns a `DateTime`.
Hence, you do not have to cope with various strings.

EDIT: Regarding cultures `date.ToString(new CultureInfo("en-US"))`

Comment: If I select date from calender as Calender1.selected date its return me like 12/12/2013 06:00:00 ص .And code unable to read this string as PM, I can use replace function but I have to use around 15 language and its not possible to add replace function for all 15 languages.

Comment: please be aware, it returns a DateTime and not a string. -> that's an advantage instead of directly working with a string --- the representation of a string (datetime -> string) can be made -if necessary - with String.Format (check msdn) --- that's another tale http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: My Date format is MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt When I select Calender1.SelectedDate in Arabic culture its return "03/08/34 12:00:00 ص" as date, but my database only accept en-us culture and SQL query returns error as datetime out of bound. I can't change my date format because I am working on a live site –